# canvas app mobile link

Tags: ios, mobile, url-routing, facebook-canvas

We have a Facebook canvas app that is configured and works properly on mobile browsers. However, if I provide a link to that app on Facebook and somebody clicks the link from the iOS Facebook App, Facebook gives an error saying that the canvas app isn't configured properly. If I take the same URL and paste it into the mobile Safari browser, it loads just fine. What can I do to make it load properly from within the Facebook App?